React Reconciler: Purpose of lastFullyObservedContext in ReactFiberNewContext.js
In the React source code(version 19.0.0), specifically in the file packages/react-reconciler/src/ReactFiberNewContext.js, I've noticed something that seems inconsistent:
The variable lastFullyObservedContext is only ever assigned the value null. However, there's a condition that checks if (lastFullyObservedContext === context).
Given that lastFullyObservedContext is always null, this condition will always evaluate to false, as it's comparing null to a context object.
Here are my questions:

What is the purpose of the lastFullyObservedContext variable?
Is the condition if (lastFullyObservedContext === context) intentional, or could this be a potential bug?
Are there any scenarios where lastFullyObservedContext could have a non-null value that I'm missing?

I'd appreciate any insights into the reasoning behind this code structure or if this is indeed an oversight in the implementation.
I'm referring to the current main branch of the React repository as of [insert date here].
Would you like me to explain or elaborate on any part of this draft
